# Identifying Shell Tabs in renderer for iOS in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I created a custom renderer for adding badges to some of the `Shell` tabs in my .NET MAUI app.

In my `AppShell`, I define multiple tab sets -- see below. In the Android version of my custom renderer, I didn't have any problems identifying tabs using the `Title` but in the iOS renderer, I can't seem to find a way to identify tabs.

Has anyone tackled something like this? If so, I'd appreciate some suggestions on how I can identify tabs.

Here's my `AppShell.xaml`:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
   <Tab Title="One" Icon="one.png">
      <ShellContent Route="OnePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local.OnePage}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Two" Icon="two.png">
      <ShellContent Route="TwoPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local.TwoPage}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Three" Icon="one.png">
      <ShellContent Route="ThreePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local.ThreePage}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png">
   <Tab Title="Four" Icon="four.png">
      <ShellContent Route="FourPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local.FourPage}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Five" Icon="five.png">
      <ShellContent Route="FivePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local.FivePage}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

And here's my custom renderer for iOS:

```
public class TabBadgeRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new BadgeShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker();
    }
}

class BadgeShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
{
   public override void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
   {
      base.UpdateLayout(controller);

      // I want to identify the tab here e.g. "Home" or "Settings"
      // controller.Title always seem to be NULL
      // I want to do something like
      if(controller.Title == "Home")
      {
         // Handle placing the badge
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following code to identify the page,

```
class CustomShellTabBarAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
{
    public override void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
    {
        // get the "Home" or "Settings" FlyoutItem Title
        string title = ((ShellItemRenderer)controller).ShellItem.Title;

        UITabBar tb = controller.TabBar;

        foreach(var item in tb.Subviews)
        {
            
            //pay attention to the index here, it depends on how you design your tab. Easily get a exception here.
            UILabel? label = item.Subviews[1] as UILabel; 
            if (label?.Text == "One")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("I have found page one");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this approach identifies the tab by iterating through all of them. I was hoping to identify the “set” so that I don’t have to loop through all the tabs to find the one I’m looking for. Using my example above, if I need to add a badge to tab 5, I literally have to check every single tab in both `FlyoutItem`’s before I get to it. It would be great if I can check the set ie `FlyoutItem` and if it’s not Settings, I’d skip it.

Comment: You may want this ```string title = ((ShellItemRenderer)controller).ShellItem.Title;``` to get FlyoutItem title

Comment: Thank for trying and I was certain your suggestion would work but for some reason, on iOS, the `Title` for `ShellItemRenderer` always seems to be `null`. I'm now using a slightly modified and slightly more efficient version of your answer. Instead of a `foreach` loop, I just use the index i.e. `if(controller.TabBar.Items.Count() == 3 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller.TabBar.Items[2].Title) && controller.TabBar.Items[2].Title == "Three")`